# Package ffmpeg_kit_flutter: ^5.1.0 does not have libmp3lame

Tags: android, flutter, ffmpeg

some time already working with audio conversion? i used the flutter_ffmpeg: package but now the official package is ffmpeg_kit_flutter: but the libmp3lame library is not working has anyone experienced this?

```
Future _loadFileSalvar(nome,path) async {
  String newPath = "";
  var directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
  List<String> paths = directory!.path.split("/");
  for (int x = 1; x < paths.length; x++) {
    String folder = paths[x];
    newPath += "/" + folder;
  }
  newPath = newPath;
  directory = Directory(newPath+"/$nome.mp3");
  File file1 = File(directory.path);


  String audioSampleFile = path;
  String audioOutputFile = directory.path;


  String ffmpegCommand = "ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i $audioSampleFile -c:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 2 -ar 22050 $audioOutputFile";



  FFmpegKit.executeAsync(ffmpegCommand, (session) async {
    final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();
    print("returnCode $returnCode");
  });



}
```

would have to return mp3 from wav conversion

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

#1 copy this code:
ext.flutterFFmpegPackage = 'full'

#2 paste it in:
./android/build.gradle

Comment: i used this but the plugin updated

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).